# Finding a value to minimise an equation using R

Tags: r

I'm looking to find the value of x which will minimise a function where x can be any positive integer up to the value set by n. For example the equation below,

f(x)=xcos(yx^2)

where n and y are values which can be set & x{1,2,...,n}

Had a try with the optimise function but can't seem to get anywhere.

I apologise if this is a really basic question, I'm just starting out so my understanding of R isn't great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `n` is very large, the natural thing to do is to just compute the vector of function values, use `min` to find its smallest value, and use `which` to find where it occurs:

```
> n <- 100000
> y <- 12345
> x <- 1:n
> v <- x*cos(y*x)
> which(v == min(v))
[1] 99986
> v[99986]
[1] -99979.1
```

If `f(x)` isn't vectorized, you would have to use `sapply` in defining `v`:

```
v <- sapply(x,f)
```

If `n` is large, the above approach might be inadequate. Without special assumptions on `f` there wouldn't be any alternative, but if you knew that e.g. there was a unique local min (which would also be the global min that you seek) then a bisection method could be used. You could also do things like minimize it for real numbers in `[1,n]` and then round to an integer. That would be a reasonable heuristic for any reasonably tame continuous `f(x)`.